# Is There Literature on Individual Demand Cap (in Housing Market)?

Tags: reference-request, supply-and-demand, markets, housing

Some (obv. very left) politicians in germany propose to impose that owning housing should be capped at what a person does use him/herself. That is, you should not be allowed to own housing for investment purposes.

Leaving the practiability issues aside, has an individual demand cap (maybe in markets other than housing) been studied in the economic literature?

Comment: Hi, welcome to economics.se. Opinion based questions whether we should have some policy or not are strictly off topic on this site (see our help center), asking for literature review for effects of such caps or even literature on such caps in general is completely fine and can stay here but you should change the question in the title, I changed it for you to something that I think reflects the body of the question, if you disagree with my edit you can change it to something else just please make sure the question is not opinion based

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense! I edited further to make clear that general results for any market are useful. Maybe there even is an established term for such a "demand cap" in the literature.

Comment: I would only say that this case could be extremely simplified to view the total demand as the sum of two demand curves, one for homeowners and one for non-homeowner investors.  Disallowing investors then causes the demand curve to shift lower.  Since it's so simplified I'll leave it as a comment rather than as an answer.